# How to convert a slice of int to a slice of string

Tags: go

Well, I created a slice of int like this:

```
list_of_id := []string {1,2,3,4}
```

My code would do a check if a variable in my slice (`list_of_id`):

```
func contains(s [] int, input int) bool {
    for _, v := range s {
        if v == input {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func main() {
    list_of_id := [] int {1,2,3,4}
    fmt.Println(contains(list_of_id, 1))
}
```

I want to create a function with the flexibility that I could input `1` or  `"1"` as well.

My intention is to create an `if` `else` condition in which the slice of int `[] int {1,2,3,4}` will be converted into a slice of string `[] string {"1","2","3","4"}` to check again.

Anddddd, I don't know how to do so. I tried to google it out but all I found is a solution to convert this `[] int {1,2,3,4}` to this `"{1,2,3,4}"`

Comment: You could use interface and assersions

Comment: Your best bet would be to either convert all of them into integer before calling `contains` function, or making the array an array of interfaces and using type assertion. https://tour.golang.org/methods/15 . Be mindful of having a default case where user doesn't input an integer or an string.

Comment: "flexibility that I could input 1 or "1" as well." you mean the slice elements are strings or the "input" is a string?

Answer (score 4):

```golang
import "strconv"

func contains(s [] int, input interface{}) bool {
    switch i := input.(type) {
    case int:
        for _, v := range s {
            if v == i {
                return true
            }
        }
    case string:
        for _, v := range s {
            if strconv.Itoa(v) == i {
                return true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/02J1f77n_aM

Answer (score 1):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func contains(s []int, input interface{}) bool {
    var c int
    var err error
    switch input.(type) {
    case int:
        c = input.(int)
    case string:
        tmp := input.(string)
        c, err = strconv.Atoi(tmp)
    }

    if err != nil {
        return false
    }

    for _, v := range s {
        if v == c {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func main() {
    list_of_id := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    fmt.Println(contains(list_of_id, 3))
    fmt.Println(contains(list_of_id, 5))
    fmt.Println(contains(list_of_id, "1"))
    fmt.Println(contains(list_of_id, "6"))
}
```

Here [example](https://play.golang.org/p/C9BGAuuM1Rq)